# Binding two viewmodel's with different hierarchy to one model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview, viewport3d

I have viewport3d with entities, and treeview with hierarchical structure of that entities. Treeview is binded from class hierarchy, something like this:

```
public class SomeDataObject
{
    private ObservableCollection<SomeDataObject> _children;
    private string _OtherProperty;

    public SomeDataObject()
    {
        this._children = new ObservableCollection<SomeDataObject>();
        //other initialization
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SomeDataObject> Children
    {
        get
        {
            return this._children;
        }
        set{ _children = value; }
    }

    public string OtherProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return this._OtherProperty;
        } 
        set{ _OtherProperty = value; }  
    }
}
```

I would like to bind to viewport only OtherProperty of all objects, without the hierarchy. 
Viewport provides binding from ObservableCollection, but does not include the ancestors. Therefore do not have access to OtherProperty in lower levels.

I think about two separate viewmodels, but I don't know how to design the communication between different viewmodel's.

I found that solution:
http://blog.quantumbitdesigns.com/2008/07/22/programmatically-selecting-an-item-in-a-treeview/
but of course this is roundabout way. 
I would like to automatically update changes in the viewmodels and model.

What is the best solution in such cases?

EDIT:
This is XAML for treeview:

```
    <TreeView Grid.Column="0" Name="MainTreeView">
      <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfTreeViewTricks:SomeDataObject}"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="TreeViewItem:"/>
            <TextBlock Margin="1,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=OtherProperty}"/>
          </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
      </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

and it's work.

[image]

The problem is with bind that hierarchical structure to the viewport, beacase viewport allow binding in following way:

```
<ht:HelixViewport3D ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" Background="{ht:LinearGradientBrush Gray, White}"/>
```

where Objects is a property of DataContext:

```
public ObservableCollection<Visual3D> Objects { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can you please show us the xaml and tell us what you want to bind exactly? Also do you really want to set the private field `_children` in the constructor or rather the property?

Comment: Sorry, it's just an example, I wrote more, I hope that this explains.